# Bridge between networks

Tags: networking, linux-networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, bridge

I'm beginner and I'm trying to set bridge between two networks in Virtual Box. I've created two VMs (Debian1 and Debian2) and for network settings I set Debian1 to **intnet1**(Internal network) and Debian2 to **intnet2**(Internal network).

Next, content of the /etc/network/interface of Debian 1:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.10.2/24

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports enp0s3
address 192.168.30.2/24
gateway 192.168.30.1
```

For Debian2:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.20.2/24

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports enp0s3
address 192.168.30.3/24
gateway 192.168.30.1
```

I have installed `bridge-utils`.

After I tried to ping machines, I get *192.168.30.3 Destination Host Unreachable*.

When I set both VMs on the same internal network it works. I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: A bridge requires at least two physical interfaces to make sense.

Comment: Hello, there are several issues with your question, for example from where are you pinging the debian2 machine? From debian1 or the host? Also, what is the goal you're trying to achieve through bridging? Generally bridging on OS-level must be done with two different interfaces, you have created a bridge with your main interface as your bridge_port without any other interface to join it and this is done on the VM level which doesn't make any sense at all. Please state your exact goal and requirement so others can help you.